# Making tablet-specific behavior. Is it SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE or me?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which will be used mainly on phones, but which some users will use on a tablet.    For the tablet users I want to configure some additional features.   I'm testing it on a phone (Galaxy S phone - 480 x 800) and a tablet (Galaxy Tab 10.1" - 800 x 1280).   Using the following code . . .

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {     
    Toast.makeText(this, "Tablet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {     
    Toast.makeText(this, "Phone" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
else   {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Neither" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

. . . the phone comes up as "phone" and the tablet comes up as "neither".    But [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) says that SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE is "at **least** approximately 480x640 dp units."

BTW, *getResources().getConfiguration()* on the tablet says screenWidthDp is 1280 and screenHeightDp is 752.      So what am I doing wrong that the tablet isn't getting detected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just tested on my Galaxy Tab:
You need to also heck for Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE.

Comment: i think honeycomb. You can use the constant instead: 4 (0x00000004)